# how to properly put back the code after git reset to an existing commit hash?

Tags: git

Scenario:

```
my commit = 123423423423423423423423
person A's commit = asdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdf
person B's commit = 23423423423423423423443
```

now my commit cannot yet pushed to prod, so I hard reset using person A's commit

```
git reset --hard asdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdf

git push -f origin master
```

then after resetting, I noticed my codes from this commit `123423423423423423423423` is still in my files. The question now is, how to git add these and re-commit and push if they appear as unmodified because they were previously committed and pushed before the hard reset.

Comment: I think you can checkout to the person A's commit first, then push it to the master, add your changes and push again

Comment: as I said, even after doing hard reset, my codes are still in my local, so if I do git status, the files doesn't appeared as modified because they were previously committed.. so what should I do ?

Comment: I don't ask you to reset, but instead checkout to a commit sir

Comment: you mean checkout that specific hash that I used in hard reset ? , but I already used the said hash during hard reset

Comment: yes, that will allow you to go directly to that commit, however I still suggest to research first, as I might be mistaken

Comment: reset hard deletes only those commits that were not yet pushed

Comment: I see, so that's the reason why my codes are still in my files, it only deletes the commit thing

Comment: this is quite troublesome to re-add my codes after checking out to a specific commit ..aren't there anyway or workaroudn ?

Comment: I would gladly answer your question if I knew on how to achieve it, unfortunately I do not know

Comment: Are the changes you're still seeing marked as "modified" or "untracked"?

Comment: @LightBender , neither 'modified' nor 'untracked'

Comment: is your commit an ancestor of the commit from person A?

Comment: @LightBender , no , person A committed different files... the thing is after I hard reset and force the remote...then I git pull, my codes are there, does that mean my codes were already merged?

Comment: most likely, can you show us the output of this command: `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all` (feel free to anonymize)

Comment: @LightBender       https://paste.ofcode.org/yzQjhTXbHmKfSXHzrVu2UK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154741/discussion-between-lightbender-and-sasori).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though your force push was rejected by your server, then when you pulled the master branch down again, your local branch was updated to the remote and your original commit was restored.

`git reset --hard` is, perhaps, the sharpest tool in the git toolbox, one of the only non-plumbing commands that can actually permanently delete code. Roughly translated as "move my branch to , delete all my local modifications, reset my index, and checkout that version of the code at ." Any uncommitted code will be permanently lost here.

`git push -f` is a pretty close second, with the added fun that it's the one most likely to screw up the rest of your team. Roughly translated this one is "I don't care if other people have pushed changes to the sever, I want my changes out there, so delete theirs to make it happen." This is so dangerous, that most git servers disable this feature by default or at the very least require administrator level privileges to accomplish it. There are some scenarios where is it advisable, but it requires great caution and a full understanding of the ramifications.

If your code has already been pushed to the remote and you want to remove it, you are almost always better off using git [revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) to reverse the changes as a new commit and push that to the server instead. Gets you to the same place without nearly as much risk.